# Error in Dixon's Book?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Dixon's Book:

Exercise 2.1.6: Suppose $G$ is $k$-transitive for some $k > 2$, and $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of G. Show that N is $(k-1)$-transitive.

But we have in Wielandt's book:

Theorem 9.9. A normal subgroup $Ν \neq 1$ of a $k$-fold  transitive group $G \neq S_n$  of degree n $(k > 2)$ is in general $(k-1)$-fold transitive. There are exceptions only in the case $n=2^m$, $k = 3$, in which case $N$ may be a regular elementary Abelian $2$-group.

Exceptions in the exercise does not mentioned!

Comment: There are many examples of doubly transitive subgroups of $S_n$ that do not contain $A_n$. The smallest has order $20$ with $n=5$.

Comment: Sorry! I was so wrong on that question!

Comment: Yes, the exercise you quote from Dixon's book is wrong. There are $3$-transitive groups of degree $2^n$ for all $n>1$ with a normal regular subgroup of order $2^n$. The smallest such example is $S_4$.